# Giving a variable a value of 1 or 0 based on whether another variable appears in query results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query `$sqlStr4` that "selects" these fields from a MySQL database:

```
loginid
username
created
```

The query `$sqlStr4` is limited to 10 rows / results.

I also have the following variable:

```
$u = $_SESSION['username'];
```

I would like to assign another variable `$topten` a value of 1 if `$u` equals any of the ten `username` fields returned by the query `$sqlStr4`, and a value of 0 if it does not.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<?php

$u = $_SESSION['username'];
$topten = 0;

$result = mysql_query($sqlStr4);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if ($row['username'] == $u) {
    $topten = 1;
    break;
  }
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had pasted the query, we'd be able to provide a fixed version.  You can do this multiple ways, but one would be to add a column to your query and use a CASE statement.

```
select *, CASE WHEN username = '$u' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as topten
from ...
```

This is just an example.. obviously to prevent SQL injection you should parameterize it, or use mysql_real_escape_string(), or a stored procedure, etc etc...

EDIT:  I see you want the variable to be in PHP... so you would need to loop through the array to check each one.  What is the problem you're having?...

```
$topten = 0;
if ($result) {
   while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      if ($record['username'] == $u) $topten = 1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like this...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlStr4))
{
    $topten = ($u == $row['username']) ? 1 : 0;
    // the rest of your processing code here
}
```

There may well be better solutions for your situation. Would be easier if you posted some code!

Comment: That will reset the `$topten` value to zero if subsequent records don't match.

Comment: @OMG - it totally depends on what the OP wants it for. If they're simply checking this, then they can just use `mysql_num_rows()` on a query. I've made the assumption that he wants to loop through and do something with the rows, therefore he'd want the value to be reset each time. A simple `if ($topten) break;` could be added if this check was all the OP wanted to do, but in that case I'd recommend he rethought his query!